# How to use params in MERN to post and get data

Tags: reactjs, express, parameters, axios, mern

I am making an authentication system in MERN.

So,
I want when someone login to post that data so I can get it later with req.params.

To post the data I want to use react using axios I just want to know how we can save that so we can req.params.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I already use MongoDB - mongoose in my app so I decided to use mongoose-connect to save my params.

Here is how I did it:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(My_URL)
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(session({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: 'secret here',
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}))
```

Hope it helped :)